# Including tables without using ToList when GroupBy

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

The tables I included in my query are not included in the query after the `groupby`.

but if I do a `tolist` before `groupby`, the problem is solved, but it didn't seem like a very good solution. Is it possible for me to solve this problem in a different way?

```cs
  [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetMostPurchased()
var mostRequestUsers = await dbContext.UserProducts 
    .Include(x => x.Products).Include(x => x.User)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.UserId, x.ProductId })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        MostPurchased = g.Key.ProductId,
        UserId = g.Key.UserId,
        Count = g.Count(),

        // how can i get the following data fields? After grouping, I cannot access the 
        "UserProducts" and "Products" table.

        ProductName = g.Select(x => x.Product.Name),
        ProductPrice = g.Select(x => x.Product.Price),
        ProductDesc = g.Select(x => x.Product.Desc),
   

        UserFirstName = g.Select(x => x.User.UserFirstName),
        UserLastName = g.Select(x => x.User.UserLastName ),
        UserPhoneNumber = g.Select(x => x.User.UserPhoneNumber)
        //

    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Count).First());

    return mostRequestUsers;
```

```
// UserProducts 
ID  UserId  ProductId
1   10      1
2   10      2
3   10      3
4   11      4
5   11      5
6   11      6
6   11      4
6   11      3
6   11      2
6   12      1
6   12      4
6   12      5

// User
ID  FirstName LastName
1   Tom         Jack
2   Brad        Pitt
3   John        Rock

// Product
ID  ProductName Price
1   Apple       20
2   Dell        30
3   Lenovo      40
```

##### my purpose: I want to list the most purchased products by users by user ID.

```
UserId: 10, MostPurchased: 1, Count: 2, ProductName: null, ProductPrice : null, UserFirstName: null, UserLastName : null

UserId: 11, MostPurchased: 2, Count: 3, ProductName: null, ProductPrice : null, UserFirstName: null, UserLastName : null

UserId: 12, MostPurchased: 3, Count: 2, ProductName: null, ProductPrice : null, UserFirstName: null, UserLastName : null
```

Comment: `it doesnt work` because it would result in meaningless SQL. You can't have non-aggregate columns in the SELECT clause when you use GROUP BY. What if there are 20 names in the group? Which *single* value should the server return? Smallest? Largest? The average? A random one? You have to specify the aggregate function, eg `g.Min(p=>p.Car.Name)`

Comment: What is the *actual* problem? Using GROUP BY to get a unique string column is meaningless. `GROUP BY` is used to aggregate and calculate some statistic. What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: `.GroupBy(x => new { x.UserId, x.ProductId })` has no sense, It should be Primary Key

Comment: Show your model and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `are not included in the query after the groupby` yes, that's what `GROUP BY`, the SQL clause, does. It groups rows and returns only a single row per group, with the GROUP BY columns and the statistics calculated for that group. There are no other columns, much less related tables, after a GROUP BY

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I added the return list.

Comment: This is almost certainly [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X and assume Y (using GroupBy) is the solution. When that didn't work you asked about Y, not the actual problem X. What is the *actual* problem X that you thought can be solved with GROUP BY? The only reason you'd want `GROUP BY` but still return all columns is that `UserProducts` is a many-to-many table but `UserID` and `ProductID` aren't unique, allowing duplicate rows. That would be a design bug, not a query problem.

Comment: @yasara6647, show your model classes.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I don't have any model. I'mreturning the data returned from the query..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I reach my goal?
problems similar to mine are usually solved with groupby. How can I solve it without Grupby? @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1):

`Include` do not work with `GroupBy` and can be omitted. Just add needed field to grouping key:

```cs
var users = dbContext.User
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.UserId, x.CarId, x.Car.Name })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        UserId = g.Key.UserId,
        CarId = g.Key.CarId,
        CarName = g.Key.Name
    };
```

Or rewrite query to use `Distinct()`

```cs
var users = dbContext.User
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        x.UserId, 
        x.CarId, 
        CarName = x.Car.Name 
    })
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I also get the user's "FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber" fields in Select. Do I need to group these too? Like this: .GroupBy(x => new { x.UserId, x.CarId, x.Car.Name, x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.PhoneNumber..... e.g })   is this a correct approach?

Comment: @yasara6647 what are you trying to do and why are you using `Group By` at all when you want to return all rows? EF Core doesn't change the fact you're executing SQL, and SQL's GROUP BY *eliminates* non-key columns

Comment: Include full query in question, do not simplify `GroupBy` query if you need correct answer.

Comment: @yasara6647, why do you need GroupBy for such query? GroupBy is used for aggregation.

Comment: @yasara6647 the edit makes even less sense. `GROUP BY` is used to calculate statistics. You aren't calculating anything here. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? It won't be solved by `GroupBy`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to list the most purchased products by users by user ID.
How can I do this without using groupby?